# Launch or eject? Whats the difference?

Tags: american-english, word-difference, british-english

> "Is a fighter being launched from aircraft carrier or ejected?"

Referring to dictionary:

> **launch (something)**: *to send something such as a spacecraft, weapon, etc., into space, into the sky, or through water*.
>
> **eject something (from something)** : *to push something out suddenly and with a lot of force

Launch - doesn't explain what force we use to do it. I even came to the conclusion that word "sling" would be better than launch.

Answer (score 2):

The system used to *propel* a fighter jet from the deck of an aircraft carrier is actually called an ["Aircraft Catapult"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_catapult).  A catapult is an ancient siege weapon used to throw large rocks at an enemy:

[image]

The verb "to catapult (something)" means something similar to "launch", *to throw outwards or into the air with extreme force*.

[image]

The aircraft catapult system is actually being (or has been) replaced by something called the [Electromagnetic Aircraft Launch System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_Aircraft_Launch_System).  So certainly "launch" is an appropriate verb for this action, especially since it conveys a sense of *intended action*.  You plan to *launch* something -- it shouldn't happen by accident.

"Eject" is not appropriate, for two reasons.  *One*, "to eject" means to push something out, yes, but not usually if that thing can move under its own power.  *Two*, to *eject* something implies it is not wanted, or defective in some way, or extraneous to the mechanism.

In fighter aircraft, the pilot(s) can *eject* from the plane if it is too damaged to fly, or they are in danger of being destroyed.  This is done by the use of an *ejection seat* which often is a rocket-propelled device to push the pilot forcefully out of the aircraft.

[image]

It's important not to mix these up when talking about fighter jets.  It's normal to *launch* the fighter from the aircraft carrier, but not so good if the pilot has to *eject* from the fighter.

"Sling" implies a kind of *throwing* action using some sort of device for added leverage.  An ancient sling is just a pocket for a rock, on the end of a rope or piece of cloth:

[image]

A related method of throwing things is a *slingshot*, which uses some kind of elastic or spring mechanic to throw an object:

[image]

To some extent, you can say that you *slingshot* a fighter from the deck of a carrier -- but real Navy personnel might look at you funny.  I think they prefer "launch".

Comment: Comprehensive description. Now i understand the difference.i didn't take in to account that whole process is more complicated and eject seemss to be a little bit inappropriate.

Comment: @user63306  I don't think it's any more complicated than any other language.  Most of these verbs are based on historical devices, like for example the verb "to bolt" which is based on an old English word for "arrow".  As with any other language, once you start learning synonyms you have to learn the subtle differences, if any.

Comment: I have decided lately to go deeper into details about similar words and yes it has changed my mindset. Sometimes words are confusing or funny, for example "confident" in polish literally means "snitch" so you can imagine how surprised i was.

Comment: @user63306  I wonder if that's just slang based on your country's experience during the Cold War?  There are many words in English that have a great many meanings in slang.

Comment: I don't know origin of this word, i spell it "konfident" but sounds same. I noticed that english slang is "complex" subject. I remember when i bumped into my female-friend and i told her " sry i bumped you". ;)

Comment: @user63306 - there is a word "confidant" (person), different from the verb "confident", you may want to look it up.